# What version clang is in Xcode 3?

Tags: xcode, clang, llvm-clang

How do I figure which version of clang that Xcode use?

It's 1.5 in Xcode, yet the official llvm-clang is 2.7. Are they the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use clang -v to find out.